# Jpg file not found

Tags: graphics, pdftex

This is an example from a file that used to run perfectly with pdflatex under MiKTeX. But now I get an error about file not found. I did update MiKTeX recently, but don't see why that should have made any changes.

```
\documentclass[pdftex]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{grffile}
\begin{document}
\includegraphics{../Pictures/s}
\end{document}
```

However, if I add a graphicspath command, then suddenly it works, even thoug ../Pictures/s is not relative to the graphicspath!

```
\documentclass[pdftex]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{grffile}
\graphicspath{{c:/Users/helmeras_adm/Documents/Astronomy/Pictures/}}
\begin{document}
\includegraphics{../Pictures/s}
\end{document}
```

Writing \includegraphics{c:/Users/helmeras_adm/Documents/Astronomy/Pictures/s} does work, but it seems like includegraphics with relative pathnames does not work unless I add a (seemingly irrelevant) graphicspath.

I like to consider myself as fairly good with LaTeX, and feel pretty stupid right now. Would be grateful for any help! Thanks!

Comment: Did you try adding the extension explicitly? If there a folder “s” inside “Pictures” or files with the name “s” and different extensions, it might be the thing. Besides that, does the folder name “Pictures” start with a capital “P”?
\includegraphics[height=8cm]{../Pictures/s.jpg}

Comment: Yes, I tried using the extension, too. (In fact I normally do include the extension.) And yes, it's Pictures with a capital P. And there are no spaces in the filenames.

Comment: Check who's the owner and the permissions for the Pictures folder and for the s.jpg file inside it.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but I am the owner and I have full permissions, and the user profile I use have admin rights. However, I'm not claiming to fully understand all aspects of how MikTeX handles this.